# Extracting specific coordinates from a specific contour, within a contours list that was detected from cv2.findContours

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, opencv3.0

I have a multidimensional array as shown below

```
Contour[0] = [[(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3)]]

Contour[1] = [[(x4,y4),(x5,y5),(x6,y6),(x7,y7),(x8,y8)]]
```

How to extract `(x1,y1)` and `(x3,y3)` from `contour[0]` and `(x4,y4)` and `(x8,y8)` from `contour[1]`?

Comment: what is the type of contour (array is not a type in python)? looks like a numpy matrix, is it? what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Contour[0][0][0] ---> ('x1', 'y1')
Contour[1][0][0] ---> ('x4', 'y4')
Contour[1][0][4] ---> ('x8', 'y8')
```